# variable definition where function is called multiple times to read a file

Tags: c, memory-management

I had to read a file containing 10+ million records(file easily running in GBs). Here is the confusing part ->

I am using a function like this to read the records (lines):

```
int funcA()
{
   char arr[1000] = "";
   int return_value=0;

   /*while EOF is not reach
    {
       read the FILE and store each line (record) from the file in arr
       return_value = funB(arr);       //function called to break and store arr into several variables - check the definition 
    }*/
    return 0;
}

int funcB( int *arr)
{
    //variables in which content of arr will be saved
   /*int  var_1;    
     char var_2;
    .
    .
    .
    .
     char var_n;*/
   return 0;
}
```

I have coded exactly like above and it works fine (in `C` language) but I am currently doing it in test environment - in above function `funB` the function will be called as many times as there are no. of records (lines) in that file. So if the file has 10 million records then this `funB` will be called 10 million times and in production there is always memory shortage - even when there is no dynamic memory used in this I am afraid that this function will not get memory for the local variable as it is put on the stack and freed millions of times - my question is should I make the variables global? By doing so It won't be needed to create variables whenever this function is called and then freed BUT at the same time I'll have to `memset` the global memory on each call to this function which can slow down the entire process.

What should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge the stack is (or will likely be) a fixed size of memory, it is not dynamically allocated or freed. Its just a stack pointer that is changed.

Note however, that the stack size is limited.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310658/how-much-stack-usage-is-too-much

I believe the performance difference will be small, the bottleneck will be reading the file.